# JavaScript innerText

Tags: innertext

I am new to JS. I'm trying to run this line of code that will save a count of numbers at each click with an embedded text. But on running it I'm having this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerText')

Here is my code

JavaScript

```
 let saveEl = document.getElementById("save-el")
 let countEl = document.getElementById("count-el")
 let count =0

 function increment(){
     count+=1 
     countEl.innerText=count
 }                        

 function save(){
     let countStr= count + " - "
     saveEl.innerText+=countStr 
     countEl.innerText=0
     count=0
 }
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
     <h1><strong>People Entered:</strong></h1>
    <h2 id="count-el">0</h2>
<script src="index.js"></script>
<div class="container-btn">
<button id="increment-btn" onclick="increment()">INCREMENT</button>
<button id="save-btn" onclick="save()">SAVE</button>
<p id="save-el">Previous entries: </p>
</div>  
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving your `<script>` tag to the end of your `<body>`, or only run it on DOM load:

```js
let count = 0
var saveEl;
var countEl;

function increment() {
  count += 1
  countEl.innerText = count
}

function save() {
  let countStr = count + " - "
  saveEl.innerText += countStr
  countEl.innerText = 0
  count = 0
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  saveEl = document.getElementById("save-el")
  countEl = document.getElementById("count-el")
})
```

```html
<h1><strong>People Entered:</strong></h1>
<h2 id="count-el">0</h2>
<div class="container-btn">
  <button id="increment-btn" onclick="increment()">INCREMENT</button>
  <button id="save-btn" onclick="save()">SAVE</button>
  <p id="save-el">Previous entries: </p>
</div>
```

If your JavaScript is before the HTML elements, they won't exist in the page when your JavaScript loads, so `document.getElementById` will return `null`. However, if you wait to set the variables until those elements exist (either because they're listed before the `<script>` tag, or because the DOM content has loaded), they'll be found.